# stable_sort missing operator- with custom compare funtion defined

Tags: c++

I call this

```
bool cmpNAME(const PlayerCard& a, const PlayerCard& b){
    return (a.Name < b.Name);//Name is std::string
}
list<PlayerCard> tmp;
//fill tmp
stable_sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), cmpNAME);//error at this line
```

and compiler gives me error that its missing operator- for PlayerCard, but why when I defined comparator for this structure

error I am getting: `/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h|3508|error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘std::_List_iterator<PlayerCard>’ and ‘std::_List_iterator<PlayerCard>’)|`

What I want to achieve is to compare names and if they are same, compare them by order I pushed them into list

Comment: When posting questions about errors, please include the *actual*, *complete* and *unedited* error log.

Comment: Also, when your compiler complains about certain lines and your file is quite long, post essential part with preserved line numbers, it is much easier for us to find actual error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::stable_sort` requires a random access iterator. `list`'s iterators are not random access.

Use [**`std::list::sort`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort).

Comment: I need sort to be stable

Comment: @lllook What makes you think `std::list::sort` isn't stable?